# Error with workflow in informatica 9.6. in connecting to linked sql server database

Tags: sql-server, ssms, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am trying to put data from a linked sql server database to my oracle database with a workflow. I am getting Error when I execute my workflow : Failed to create and initialize SQL OLE DB instance. Reason 14007, token not found.
I guess because the user running the query in informatica is not the same in SQL server so, i went to regedit an I changed the owner of "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID{2206CDB0-19C1-11D1-89E0-00C04FD7A82" to Administrator.
I also went to Dcomcnfg and I added there "Administrator" with all permissions. I am still getting same error.I don t know how to solve it to debug the connection to the linked database.
Can you please help?
I also chaged the odbc.ini file  (here below the parameters)

```
[Sqlserver]
Driver32=C:\WINDOWS\system32\SQLSRV32.dll
Description=DataDirect 7.1 SQL Server Wire Protocol
AlternateServers=
AlwaysReportTriggerResults=0
AnsiNPW=1
ApplicationName=
ApplicationUsingThreads=1
AuthenticationMethod=1
BulkBinaryThreshold=32
BulkCharacterThreshold=-1
BulkLoadBatchSize=1024
BulkLoadOptions=2
ConnectionReset=0
ConnectionRetryCount=0
ConnectionRetryDelay=3
Database=Mydatabase
EnableBulkLoad=0
EnableQuotedIdentifiers=0
EncryptionMethod=0
FailoverGranularity=0
FailoverMode=0
FailoverPreconnect=0
FetchTSWTZasTimestamp=0
FetchTWFSasTime=1
GSSClient=native
HostName=MSSQLSERVER
HostNameInCertificate=
InitializationString=
Language=
LoadBalanceTimeout=0
LoadBalancing=0
LoginTimeout=15
LogonID=
MaxPoolSize=100
MinPoolSize=0
PacketSize=-1
Password=
Pooling=0
PortNumber=1433
QueryTimeout=0
ReportCodePageConversionErrors=0
SnapshotSerializable=0
TrustStore=
TrustStorePassword=
ValidateServerCertificate=1
WorkStationID=
XML Describe Type=-10
```

Comment: i think i already asked this - 1. is your infa server is Windows, pls test the connection from ODBC database admin using the same user as informatica. 2. if its unix based then use `ssgodbc` to test out the connectivity. If your connectivity is fine, then make sure you are using same user and pass in informatica connection. Infa user can be different than the user connecting to SQL Server but the user mentioned in conn string should be able to connect.

Comment: `XML Describe Type=-10` ... is that actually in your ODBC.ini file? The "Token not found" error is probably because that should be `XMLDescribeType=-10` without spaces.

Comment: not 100% sure. Also when you said you are trying to connect to a linked SQL Server? Does this mean you can login to oracle and select a table from SQL Serv? if yes, then you can connect to oracle and not to SQL Dev.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning thanks for your suggestion I will change it, as you can see I left the some paramenters without value   .... I hope this will be fine. what do you think?

Comment: @Koushik Roy,  I have my infa server on windows pc, with oracle and sql developer : I am not sure I understand you Roy when you say I have to test it "from ODBC database admin".  When I do my mapping on informatica I am able to establish a connection and select tables from both (oracle and the other pc with SQL server). Is by running the workflow that It doesn't work. The mapping with Oracle source and target is working fine. This mapping with sql server "souce" and oracle "target" gives me error.With "linked" I mean that SQL server and ssms are installed on other pc of my home network/domain.

Comment: you said, `infa server on windows pc`, so it must be using some user to run infa service. Now, use that user to login, open odbc data source page (search for it), and then test out SQL server connection there. if  its  a success, all should be good. Also make sure you are using 32 or 64 bit app depending on infa bit.

Comment: yes I have 1) one pc with win 10 operating system where I installed infa server and oracle   2) another pc where I installed windows server 2019 and ssms

Comment: @Koushik RoyNow I cannot connect anymore to the remote sql server drom the ODBC Admin consolle of 1) and this is quite confusing. I went as you said to test it in ODBC admin consolle of 1) and started to create an allow inbound rule for the port and a custom one for the sql server database engine instance. When I search the SQL Server service to apply the rule to, I don t see it. What do I need to install on 1) in order to let SQL Service entry appear? I guess I have to install something in 1) right?

Comment: infa server should be able to talk to database - which means, if your DB is open to world, then make infa has outbound connectivity to DB server. if your DB is not open, make sure infa server is alowed.

Comment: the ODBC Admin consolle is fine, I can Establish the connection there. The infa server can telnet the port of the sql server. The problem is the "connection object definition" within informatica that i then use in the workflow : I tried to create one with type "Microsoft SQL Server" with or without kerberos auth and trusted connection , and one with type "ODBC" but is says I must enter a password which is empty when I connect in SSMS , so I am not able to create the exact connection object definition I used in the ODBC Admin Consolle